# Authorize failed when any not-self-signed certificate exists in trusted root certification authorities

Tags: iis, https, iis-8

I've faced this problem when deploying my web service on IIS. I set up https protocol and binded certificate.
But authorization did not work and iis returned 403 error.  Authorization had worked after deletion the only cross-certificate out of trusted root certification authorities.
Issuer of this cross-certificate was also in trusted root certification authorities.
Is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal.

If you can reproduce the issue, please check the sub status code of 403 error. I think it may be 403.16.

One cause for this error is that [non-self-signed certificates are in Trusted Root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-403-forbidden-access-website#cause-2-non-self-signed-certificates-are-in-trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store).

> There are one or more non-self-signed certificates in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate store. A non-self-signed certificate is any certificate for which the Issued To and Issued By values aren't an exact match.

Resolution is moving any non-self-signed certificated out of the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate store and into the Intermediate Certification Authorities Certificate store.

Comment: Ok. But why can't not-self-signed certificate be in Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate store? Even if its issuer certificate is also in Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate store?

Comment: As documentation said:Issued To and Issued By values aren't an exact match and not-self-signed certificate cannot in trusted root Certification Authorities Certificate store.